# Dyanic formarray in dynamic mat-tabs

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, formarray

starting from this array that returns me from an api:

```
"offerta_id": "OFF_20230413132304", 
    "offerta_daInviareACommerciale": "0",
    "tabs": [
        {
        "offerta_tab": "TABxxx",
        "articoli": [
            {
            "offerta_articoli_codice": "a2xxx213",
            "offerta_articoli_descrizione": "2xxxuno123",
            "offerta_articoli_costo": 100,
            "offerta_articoli_qta": 1,
            "offerta_articoli_margine": 20.1,
            "offerta_articoli_prezzoVendita": 150
            },
            {
            "offerta_articoli_codice": "a2xxxdue123",
            "offerta_articoli_descrizione": "2xxxdue123",
            "offerta_articoli_costo": 100,
            "offerta_articoli_qta": 100,
            "offerta_articoli_margine": 2,
            "offerta_articoli_prezzoVendita": 150
            }
        ]
        },
        {
        "offerta_tab": "TAByyy",
        "articoli": [ 
            {
            "offerta_articoli_codice": "2xxx213",
            "offerta_articoli_descrizione": "2xxxuno123",
            "offerta_articoli_costo": 100,
            "offerta_articoli_qta": 1,
            "offerta_articoli_margine": 20.1,
            "offerta_articoli_prezzoVendita": 150
            }
        ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to create a series of mat-tabs in angular (typescript), each mat-tab corresponds to an array inside "tabs", of which the value "offer_tab" is the title of the tab.
The user must be able to add as many tabs as he wants in addition to the predefined ones within the array via a button.

Within each tab, there must be a format containing n rows as many objects are inside "articles", with the respective fields indicating how many inputs there are on each row.

The user must have the ability to add empty lines with empty inputs that can be filled in with a button.

**I'm a bit struggling to understand how formArrays work.**